# Oracle SQL use of subquery simulateneously in group by & select clauses in conjunction with CASE operator

Tags: sql, select, group-by, case, with-statement

Long title and strange problem:
I want to use the with-statement in oracle SQL to reuse a sub-query as well in the select as group by clause. Additionally, I use a case statement in order to create more information and group the results. This statement however throws following error: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression.

Example query that is not working: I define a query containing the sum of the sales per product family. I sort this query and select the best selling product family out if it. As main result, I want to compare this top selling family to the sum of the sales of other product families (not one by one but all other product families grouped together). I do this following way:

```
WITH
top_family AS (
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT c.family
      FROM products c, sales d
      WHERE c.product_id=  d.product_id
      GROUP BY c.family
      ORDER BY SUM(d.quantity) DESC) 
      WHERE ROWNUM = 1)

SELECT CASE
           WHEN a.family IN (SELECT * FROM top_family)
           THEN 'Most sold category'
           ELSE 'Other categories'
       END Family, SUM(a.price*b.quantity) "Total monetary sales"
FROM products a, sales b
WHERE a.product_id =  b.product_id
GROUP BY CASE
             WHEN a.family IN (SELECT * FROM top_family)
             THEN 'Most sold category'
             ELSE 'Other categories'
         END
ORDER BY 1;
```

An interesting fact is that if I replace the sub-query 'top_family' as defined in the code above directly into the code (so replace every every place containing top_family with the select * from (select ...) statement), it works and gives the desired result.

The problem should probably be caused by using the sub-query defined in a with statement. Although I realize there are (better and more elegant) solutions than this one, I'd like to find out why I can't use the table alias "top_family" in the group by and select statement.

Comment: What if there are more than one best selling families? You are selecting only one of them by limiting by ROWNUM.

Comment: @Rachcha, that is completely true. I guess I'm making abstraction of the fact that is indeed possible that there are multiple best selling families.

Comment: Are you aware that if you rewrite the query to not use a with statement (i.e., by copy-pasting the query in the with statement where you have top_family), it still does not work in Oracle 10g? Your claim does hold though in 12c.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the `GROUP BY CASE WHEN` statement.

This statement is only compiled in the final step of execution. This way that sub-clause is witheld from the `SELECT CASE WHEN`. This null operation is returning errors.

It is also described in the SQL manual.

Answer (score 0):

After reading your requirements properly, I suggest you use something like this:

```
WITH
top_product AS (
  SELECT s1.product_id
    FROM sales s1
GROUP BY s1.product_id
  HAVING sum(s1.quantity)
          = (SELECT total_sale
               FROM (SELECT SUM(s.quantity) AS total_sale
                       FROM sales s
                   GROUP BY s.product_id
                   GROUP BY SUM(s.quantity))
              WHERE rownum = 1))

  SELECT CASE t.product_id
            WHEN null THEN 'Other categories'
            ELSE 'Most sold category'
         END Family,
         SUM(a.price*b.quantity) "Total monetary sales"
    FROM products a JOIN sales b
         ON a.product_id =  b.product_id
         LEFT JOIN top_product t ON a.product_id = t.product_id
GROUP BY CASE t.product_id
            WHEN null THEN 'Other categories'
            ELSE 'Most sold category'
         END
ORDER BY 1;
```

Comment: Strange enough, this code is missing a right parenthesis somewhere in the with clause. I edited my questions a bit: do you happen to know why my code isn't running?

Comment: Well, in that case, you the right parenthesis before the main `SELECT` statement.